# Performing an AVG on a calculated SUM value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, aggregate-functions

I want to get the Average value of a calculated SUM value but I'm getting an error stating that I "cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery."

Sample Code:

```
SELECT 
T.ReferenceNo,
Parts = ROUND(SUM(
    CASE
        WHEN T.AccountCode in ('value1', 'value2') THEN
            T.Amount
    END),2)
Labor = ROUND(SUM(
    CASE
        WHEN T.AccountCode in ('value1', 'value2') THEN
            T.Amount
    END),2)
FROM Transactions T
```

I want to return the average for both Parts and Labor but when I attempt to wrap the AVG function around them I get the error earlier described.

How should I go about correctly returning the required averages?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.   An AVG() of a SUM() will always be the SUM(), you need more than one value for compute an average.   Can you provide a little more detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want just the average instead of the sum, simply replace `SUM` with `AVG`:

```
SELECT 
T.ReferenceNo,
Parts = ROUND(AVG(
    CASE
        WHEN T.AccountCode in ('value1', 'value2') THEN
            T.Amount
    END),2)
Labor = ROUND(AVG(
    CASE
        WHEN T.AccountCode in ('value1', 'value2') THEN
            T.Amount
    END),2)
FROM Transactions T
```

And if you want the average of two values (two columns), then you could use:

```
(VALUE1 + VALUE2) / 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, either `Parts` or `Labor` could be NULL, which would confuse the simple average calculation.  I would suggest:

```
select t.ReferenceNo, t.Parts, t.Labor,
       (case when Parts is null then Labor
             when Labor is null then Parts
             else (Parts + Labor) / 2
        end) as AvgPartsLabor
from (SELECT T.ReferenceNo,
             Parts = ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN T.AccountCode in ('value1', 'value2')
                                    THEN  T.Amount
                               END),2)
             Labor = ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN T.AccountCode in ('value1', 'value2')
                                    THEN T.Amount
                               END),2)
      FROM Transactions T
      group by t.referenceNo
     ) t
```

If you wanted to explicitly treat NULL Parts and Labor values as 0, then use:

```
select t.ReferenceNo, t.Parts, t.Labor,
       (coalesce(Parts, 0) + coalesce(Labor, 0)) / 2
. . .
```